# Need to add radius borders around each of my 6 rows created

Tags: html, css, border, radius

As you can see from my html code below I have 6 columns with green borders which have not been added correctly.

I want to have a border around each of the rows and I want a radius to the right of each of these 6 rows too.

Can anyone help me out?

```
<html>
    <div id="mainContainer" style="width:100%; height:750px>
        <div id="section1Container" style="width:100%;height:15%;color:yellow green;border: solid #52D017;float:left">          
            <div id="section1ContainerLabel" style="width:28%;height:100%;color:black;font-size:40px;background-color:#52D017;float:left">
                Deals
            </div>
            <div id="section1ContainerLinksCol1" style="width:36%;height:100%;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;  float:left">

                    Deal Doc. Links</br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f1%2e%20Deals%20CEMEA&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">link to Deals CEMEA</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f2%2e%20Deals%20NEMEA&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">link to Deals NEMEA</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f3%2e%20Deals%20SEMEA&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">link to Deals SEMEA</a></br>          
            </div>          
        </div>      
        <div id="partition1" style="clear:left; width:100%;height:2%; background-color:#C0C0C0"></div>      
        <div id="section1Container" style="width:100%;height:15%;color:Zombie Green;float:left">            
            <div id="section1ContainerLabel" style="width:28%;height:100%;color:black;font-size:40px;background-color:#52D017;float:left">
                Reference               
            </div>
            <div id="section1ContainerLinksCol1" style="width:36%;height:100%;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;  float:left">

                    Deal Doc. Links</br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e2%2e%20Pricelists%20and%20Promos%2fPricelists%2fMaster%20Price%20List%20All%20Currencies&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">link to Pricelists</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e2%2e%20Pricelists%20and%20Promos%2fApproval%20Matrix&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">link to Sales Approval Matrix</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e2%2e%20Pricelists%20and%20Promos%2fUpgrade%20SKU%20%2d%20Base%20and%20Destination%20List&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">link to Upgrade SKU's</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e2%2e%20Pricelists%20and%20Promos%2fPromos&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to Promo's</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e1%2e%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines%2fD%20%2d%20ELA%20%2d%20Review%20Quote%2fNew%20Products%20%2d%20Pricing%20and%20Packaging&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to New Products-Pricing and Packaging</a></br>

            </div>

            <div id="section1ContainerLabelCol2" style="width:36%;height:100%;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;  border-right: solid #52D017; float:left">

                    Deal Doc. Links</br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.2.%20Pricelists%20and%20Promos/Pricelists/Master%20Price%20List%20All%20Currencies/2015.11.01-Master%20Price%20List_All%20Currencies-%20v1.xls">link to Master Price List for November(AllCurrencies)</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.2.%20Pricelists%20and%20Promos/Plan%20Rates/FY15%20FX%20Rates.xlsx">link to Plan Rates</a></br>


            </div>      

        </div>

        <div id="partition1" style="clear:left; width:100%;height:2%; background-color:#C0C0C0"></div>

        <div id="section1Container" style="width:100%;height:15%;color:yellow;float:left">

            <div id="section1ContainerLabel" style="width:28%;height:100%;color:black;font-size:40px;background-color:#FFFF00;float:left">

                ELA

            </div>

            <div id="section1ContainerLinksCol1" style="width:36%;height:100%;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;  float:left">

                    Deal Doc. Links</br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e1%2e%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines%2fC%20%2d%20ELA%20%2d%20IB%20process%20doc&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">link to IB Process Docs</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e1%2e%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines%2fJ%20%2d%20ELA%20%2d%20Contract%20Drafting&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to Contract Drafting</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e1%2e%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines%2fK%20%2d%20ELA%20%2d%20Booking%20Pack&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to Booking Pack</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e1%2e%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines%2fL%20%2d%20ELA%20%2d%20Post%20Q%2dEnd%20Activities&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to Post Q-End Activities</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e5%2e%20Tools%20and%20Applications%2fScorecard&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to Deal Scoring</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e3%2e%20Reporting%20and%20Tracking%2fTracking%20%2d%20ELA%20Register&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to ELA Register</a></br>

            </div>

            <div id="section1ContainerLabelCol2" style="width:36%;height:100%;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;  border-right: solid #52D017; float:left">

                    Deal Doc. Links</br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/C%20-%20ELA%20-%20IB%20process%20doc/Embedded%20ELA%20Rec.docx">link to Embedded ELA Rec</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/C%20-%20ELA%20-%20IB%20process%20doc/Broken%20OYR%20Scenarios.docx">link to Broken OYR Scenarios</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f3%2e%20Deals%20SEMEA&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">link to Enterprise Purchasing Program (EPP) Partner FAQ</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/Unlimited/ZDO%20Unlimited%20Request%20Template.xlsx">ZDO Unlimited Request Template</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/SPP/SPP%20Allocation%20Exception%20Template%20Academic%2015Q4_IE.xlsx">Link to SPP Allocation Exception Template Academic 15Q4_IE</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/SPP/SPP%20Allocation%20Exception%20Template%20Academic%2015Q4_US.xlsx">Link to SPP Allocation Exception Template Academic 15Q4_US</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/SPP/SPP%20Allocation%20Exception%20Template%20Commercial%2015Q4_IE.xlsx">Link to SPP Allocation Exception Template Commercial 15Q4_IE</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/SPP/SPP%20Allocation%20Exception%20Template%20Commercial%2015Q4_US.xlsx">Link to SPP Allocation Exception Template Commercial 15Q4_US</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/SPP/SPP%20Deal%20Desk%20Training.pptx">Link to SPP Deal Desk Training</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/OEM/Lenovo_Amendment3_SIGNED.PDF">Link to OEM Lenovo Amendment PDF</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/VPP/Migration%20plan%20vFinal.doc">Link to Migration plan vFinal</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/VPP/SRG%20Affiliates%20List.docx">Link to SRG Affiliates List</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/VPP/VPP%20Blanket%20SPFs%20Additions.xlsx">Link to VPP Blanket SPFs Additions</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/VPP/VPP%20Training%20deck%20v8[1].0.ppt">Link to VPP Training Deck</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/VPP/Vpp.next%20migration%20tracker.xlsx">Link to VPP.next Migration Tracker</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/D%20-%20ELA%20-%20Review%20Quote/Academic%20+%20Non%20Profit/ACADEMIC%20RULES.pdf">Link to Academic Rules</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.5.%20Tools%20and%20Applications/Scorecard/Score%20card%20-%20%20IB%20template%20set%20up.docx">Link to Score card-IB template set up</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.5.%20Tools%20and%20Applications/Scorecard/EDS%20Deal%20Desk%20new%20presentation.pptx">Link to Deal Scoring Training Presentation</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.5.%20Tools%20and%20Applications/ECMS/Route%20Approvals.pdf">Link To ECMS Training Doc-Routing to Approvals</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.5.%20Tools%20and%20Applications/ECMS/Send%20an%20Agreement%20for%20Signature.pdf">Link to ECMS Training Doc-Sending an Agreement for Signature</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.5.%20Tools%20and%20Applications/ECMS/Update%20an%20Agreement.pdf">Link to ECMS Training Doc-Updating an Agreement</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/Z.%20ELA%20Matrix/Quick%20Check%20Lists%20for%20ELAs.docx">Link to Quick Checklist for ELAs</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/Z.%20ELA%20Matrix/Z_ELA_MATRIX.xlsx">Link to ELA Matrix</a></br>

            </div>      

        </div>

        <div id="partition1" style="clear:left; width:100%;height:2%; background-color:#C0C0C0"></div>
        <div id="section1Container" style="width:100%;height:15%;color:Green Yellow;float:left">

            <div id="section1ContainerLabel" style="width:28%;height:100%;color:black;font-size:40px;background-color:#B1FB17;float:left">

                SPF

            </div>

            <div id="section1ContainerLinksCol1" style="width:36%;height:100%;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;  float:left">

                    Deal Doc. Links</br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e1%2e%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines%2fP%20%2d%20SPF%20%2d%20Tracker%20%2d%20Archived&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to SPF Tracker</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e1%2e%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines%2fX%2e%20Process%20Templates%2fSPF%20Excel%20Model&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to SPF Process Docs</a></br>


            </div>

            <div id="section1ContainerLabelCol2" style="width:36%;height:100%;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;  border-right: solid #52D017; float:left">

                    Deal Doc. Links</br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/Z.%20SPF%20Matrix/Manual%20SPF%20Matrix.xlsx">Link to Model N SPF Matrix</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/Z.%20SPF%20Matrix/SPF%20slides.pptx">Link to SPF Slides</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.1.%20Processes%20and%20Guidelines/Z.%20SPF%20Matrix/Template%20all%20currencies%20-%20VSPP%20SPF.xlsx">Link to VSPP Template-All Currencies</a></br>

            </div>      

        </div>

        <div id="partition1" style="clear:left; width:100%;height:2%; background-color:#C0C0C0"></div>


        <div id="section1Container" style="width:100%;height:15%;color:Blue Ivy;float:left">

            <div id="section1ContainerLabel" style="width:28%;height:100%;color:black;font-size:40px;background-color:#3090c7;float:left">

                Reporting

            </div>

            <div id="section1ContainerLinksCol1" style="width:36%;height:100%;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;  float:left">

                    Deal Doc. Links</br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e3%2e%20Reporting%20and%20Tracking&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to Reporting</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e7%2e%20Project%20Tracker%20and%20Issue%20Tracker&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to Trackers</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f4%2e%20Operations%20Management%2f4%2e3%2e%20Reporting%20and%20Tracking%2fTracking%20%2d%20Historical%20ELA%20Data&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link to Historical Data</a></br>



            </div>

            <div id="section1ContainerLabelCol2" style="width:36%;height:100%;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;  border-right: solid #52D017; float:left">

                    Deal Doc. Links</br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.7.%20Project%20Tracker%20and%20Issue%20Tracker/Ops%20Management%20-%20Project%20Tracker.xlsx">Link to Project Tracker</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.7.%20Project%20Tracker%20and%20Issue%20Tracker/Ops%20Management%20-%20Issue%20tracker.xlsx">Link to Issue Tracker</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.3.%20Reporting%20and%20Tracking/Reporting%20-%20Weekly%20Reports/01_EMEA_WarRoom_Master_File.xlsx">Link to WarRoom Master File</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.3.%20Reporting%20and%20Tracking/Reporting%20-%20Weekly%20Reports/02_EMEA_Opportunity_Master_File.xlsx">Link to Opportunity Master File</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.3.%20Reporting%20and%20Tracking/Reporting%20-%20Weekly%20Reports/03_EMEA_Cases_Master_File.xlsx">Link to Cases Master File</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.3.%20Reporting%20and%20Tracking/Reporting%20-%20Quaterly%20Reports/2015%20Q1/2015%20Q1%20ELA%20Quotes%20Analysis_v1.xlsx">Link to 2015 Q1 Quarterly Activity Report</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.3.%20Reporting%20and%20Tracking/Reporting%20-%20Quaterly%20Reports/2015%20Q2/2015%20Q2%20ELA%20Quotes%20Analysis_v2.xlsx">Link to 2015 Q2 Quarterly Activity Report</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.3.%20Reporting%20and%20Tracking/Reporting%20-%20Quaterly%20Reports/2015%20Q3/Data/2015%20Q3%20ELA%20Quotes%20Analysis_v5.xlsx">Link to 2015 Q3 Quarterly Activity Report</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/4.%20Operations%20Management/4.3.%20Reporting%20and%20Tracking/Tracking%20-%20ELA%20Register/ELA%20Register%20Q3%202015.xlsx">Link to ELA Register</a></br>


            </div>      

        </div>

        <div id="partition1" style="clear:left; width:100%;height:2%; background-color:#C0C0C0"></div>

        <div id="section1Container" style="width:100%;height:15%;color:Blueberry Blue;float:left">

            <div id="section1ContainerLabel" style="width:28%;height:100%;color:black;font-size:40px;background-color:#0041c2;float:left">

                Admin

            </div>

            <div id="section1ContainerLinksCol1" style="width:36%;height:100%;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;  float:left">

                    Deal Doc. Links</br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f6%2e%20Team%20Admin%2f6%2e1%2e%20Vacation%20Log&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link To Holiday Tracker</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f6%2e%20Team%20Admin%2f6%2e4%2e%20Contacts&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link To Contacts</a><br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f9%2e%20Sharepoint%20Admin&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link To Sharepoint Admin</a><br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fsales%2femeabusinessops%2fDocs%2fDocuments%2fDeal%20Desk%2fEMEA%2fDeal%20Desk%20Operations%2f5%2e%20Meetings&FolderCTID=0x0120006CE38424832E7F409309AE2695A37E17&View=%7bFCA5C05B%2dE017%2d4F2F%2d9CBC%2d7D17C34C3DA7%7d">Link To Meetings</a><br>

            </div>

            <div id="section1ContainerLabelCol2" style="width:36%;height:100%;color:black;background-color:#ffffff;  border-right: solid #52D017; float:left">

                    Deal Doc. Links</br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/6.%20Team%20Admin/6.1.%20Vacation%20Log/2015/2015%20EMEA%20Deal%20Ops%20Vacation%20Log.xlsx">Link 2015 Vacation Log</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/6.%20Team%20Admin/6.1.%20Vacation%20Log/2016/2016%20EMEA%20Deal%20Ops%20Vacation%20Log.xlsx">link to 2016 Vacation Log</a></br>
                    <a href="https://vmshare.vmware.com/sales/emeabusinessops/Docs/Documents/Deal%20Desk/EMEA/Deal%20Desk%20Operations/9.%20Sharepoint%20Admin/9.1.%20Sharepoint%20Backup/Ticket%201690824%20%20Request%20for%20Team%20Sharepoint%20Backup%20(Scheduled%20if%20possible).msg">link to Ticket Request for Sharepoint Backup</a></br>

            </div>  
    </div>    
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for joining us on SO! It'd be helpful if you cleaned up your post a bit to be the simplest form possible. "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem." [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a fiddle out of your example to *show* you what we can actually see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SidOfc/de4ju8a3/) - based on this and your question it looks like all you want to do is add a [border radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).

**Had to re-add the HTML as a requirement for SO**

```
<html>
    <div id="mainContainer" style="width:100%; height:750px>
        <div id="section1Container" style="width:100%;height:15%;color:yellow green;border: solid #52D017;float:left">
            ... snipped...
```

I linked a border-radius article from MDN, at the bottom you are shown how to add a border-radius to a specific corner of an element, all you have to do is include it within your inline styles to make it happen.

The reason I don't really want to figure out which element it is specifically is because it has now only become a minor exercise to add it to the right element yourself and I'm not actually sure if my fiddle is showing me what you're seeing either.

Below are some other notes while wandering through the source of your HTML

### off-topic / notes

Anyways, I'm looking at your code and see multiple other things that are to be improved if you ever wish to maintain the same code.

For one, you're using inline-styling e.g. `<div style="css..."></div>`, then I'm looking at your `</br>` tags but the `<br>` tag is either defined like `<br>` (no slash at all) or `<br />` (trailing (optional) space + slash).

The html parser doesn't cry about it since it's a common mistake so it tries to fix it for you to make it valid which is why you don't see your page breaking down in agony.

*(You can actually see the `<div>` tags turning red after a `</br>` in the fiddle)*

For the inline styles I would highly suggest (and every developer here would agree) using an [external CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) file - this will allow you to remove every inline `style="..."` from your elements and replace it with an appropiate `class="..."` attribute that will be a a pointer to all your styles.

What it'll do is basically allow you to style multiple elements in roughly the same way without having to *physically duplicate* the styles.

e.g.

```
.my-selector {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #09c;
    border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

then with the following markup

```
<div class="my-selector"></div>
<div class="my-selector"></div>
```

It should produce 2 small boxes that both have a blue background and a black 1px border.

**that** is what CSS is built for pretty much, allowing for a maintainable way of styling your website and it is a way for you to move forward if you weren't forced to use inline CSS which is only *viable / acceptable* in some cases.

Good luck!